# read single byte from PHP uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, readfile, fread

I am very new to PHP, so forgive me my ignorance.

**I have** HTML for for upload:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My PHP is (It doens't know, but hopefully it shows what I want):

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  $content = fread($_FILES["file"],10);
  echo $content;
  echo "byte10 is: " ???
  }
?>
```

**I want to:** From this uploaded file, I want to read a single byte (say byte 10). I want to print out the acscii (HEX) code for this byte. How do I do that? Do I need to save the file to the server?

(**The untimate goal** is to encrypt the file and send th eencrypted file back to the user. So I want (1) upload file (2) read each individual byte (2) perform encryption on byte level (3) save file and send it back to the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for the "ultimate goal" -- it will help us make sure that you don't do something silly by accident.

Encryption is a very complex topic.  You *should not* write your own encryption routine.  Use a complete, pre-built solution.

[Mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) is PHP's best encryption extension.  Mcrypt supports [multiple common ciphers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) including AES ("Rijndael").  [Encryption is pretty darn easy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) -- use ["CBC" mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php) for your file.

---

The [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) is a 460-ish year old substitution cipher based on a simple lookup table.

This explains the whole one-character-at-a-time thing.

While you *can* read the whole file one byte at a time, you might find it more convenient to work with a string.  You can read the entire file into a variable (through `file_get_contents` or whatever), and then use [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [the square bracket substring syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) to read the string one byte at a time.  Remember, PHP strings are just simple lists of bytes.

Given `$data` is the complete data in the file, you can process every byte thusly:

```
$length = strlen($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $byte = $data[$i];
// Or
    $byte = substr($data, $i, 1);
// Process the byte here.
}
```

This is only practical for small files (smaller than a few megabytes), as it requires loading the whole file into memory.

> I want to print out the acscii (HEX) code for this byte

You can get the *decimal* value using [`ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php), then convert that to a hexadecimal string using [`dechex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php):

```
$hex_value = dechex(ord($byte));
```

Post-substitution, you can reverse it -- use [`hexdec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) to go from hex to decimal, then [`chr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) to go from decimal to byte:

```
$converted_byte = chr(hexdec($ciphered_hex));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The encryption part is more just for fun. I want to encrypt the file using the vigenere cipher and want to try and do it all manually. (But I will for sure try to look into this Mcrypt)

Comment: @Thomas, as long as you understand that encrypting *real data* is something best suited to someone else's code, then by all means, go for it!  I'm going to update my answer in a moment with an alternative solution for you.

Comment: @Thomas, my answer has now been updated with more information on working with the data, and how to get it hex'd and back.

Comment: Excellent! I think this is exactly what I need. So as Allen Hamilton wrote below, I just do "$content = fread($_FILES["file"],??);
" to have all content as a string and then work on that string. So, what do I do if the file is "large"? (I was just wanting this to work for files maybe belew 5MB)

Comment: Ok, so something is not working with the "$content = fread($_FILES["file"],int);", that was what I started with... I guess I have to save a copy of the file on the server to be able to do any thing with the content, is that right?

Comment: @Thomas, you'll want to "process" the uploaded file first -- read @Khez's post about `move_uploaded_file`.  Once it's in a known location, then you can open it for reading.  If the file *does* get large, then you'll want to read it byte by byte, which again @Khez's post contains a decent answer to.  As long as your PHP memory limit is high enough, this shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Those would make sense when reading files larger than available memory.  I'd sooner use `fgets` with the length parameter to read a few (hundred) bytes at a time than to read `fgetc` to *always* read one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple implementations, I'm gonna give you a reusable one, using [fseek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).

```
<?php
function getByte($f,$n){
    fseek($f,$n);
    return fread($f,1);
}

$f=fopen('your_file_path');
echo getByte($f,10);
?>
```

I strongly suggest using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) before using anything $_FILES.

P.S. This can get very very expensive if you're not careful, my suggestion to you, would be to read bigger chunks and then perform operations on them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So the move_uploaded_file moves the file to the server and saves a copy there? If yes, if there a way just to extract the information without ever saving the file on the server?

Comment: No. And No. The file is saved in a temporary directory when a user uploads it. you have to move it using move_uploaded_file for various reasons. You can look at move_uploaded_file as being a very special copy file function.

Comment: Ok, so the move_uploaded_file just moves from the remporary folder to a "special copy" which is saved in "momery" somehow?

Comment: Have you looked... at the function? It moves the file from the temporary directory to another directory.

Comment: Ok, I see from the manual that one has to specify a position on the server to move the file. And so this actually "saves" the file on the server(?) Is there a way to get around actually saving the file on the server? (sorry for being slow here...)

Comment: When. The file is uploaded. It's not in memory. It's in a temporary folder. Saved. On the file server.

Comment: @Khez: unless I'm mistaken (and please correct me if I'm wrong), but `move_uploaded_file` is meant for _during_ the validation process.  After script end, if the file hasn't been "moved", it's destroyed.  Meanwhile, you are free to do size, type, etc checks on it (bringing in $_FILES` as _redundant-only_ checks, and I hope everyone realizes the importance of redundancy) to first ensure it is an acceptable upload.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer That was outside the scope of the question, of course you are right, that's the one of the reason files are sandboxed like that. But he was trying to open and read the file in the temporary directory.

Comment: @Khez: just going off "I strongly suggest using move_uploaded_file before using anything $_FILES.", so the timeline of how to process a file didn't make sense according to your example.

Comment: @bob, understood! Thanks for the catch, I get overzealous with `always`. Bad habbit.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, a string is basically an array of bytes, so you can use the fread() function to read some characters in to a string, and then access individual bytes using array notation. Eg.

```
$content = fread($_FILES["file"],10);
echo $content;
echo "byte10 is: ".$content[9]; // 9 because offset starts from 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This might actually be what I am looking fore. So this saves the first 10 bytes of the file in a string and I can just read the last byte of that string (?). So I could also just read the whole file into a string, and work byte by byte on that string and that way I don't have to save anything on the server, right?

Comment: sure, you can read the whole file in to memory if the file is small. For larger files, you can use fread() to read a number of bytes in to a buffer. The manual has an example using a while loop and feof() here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php